# Boolean statement returning true when should be false (Using and & or)

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean

I have a boolean statement using `and` & `or` to determine if it's true or false. The result should be `false` but it is returning `true`. Why is this? What can I do to make it actual output the real answer.

If I comment out the last section (`or nighttime==False`) it will give me the right answer, but it is something I need to include and it doesn't make sense to make it an `and` because I want to have it so that if headlights are out, it's only okay to drive during the day or when nighttime is false.

```
      got_car=True
      drunk=False
      gas=2 #(gallons) - gas currently in the tank of the car
      distance=100 #miles from home
      mpg=35 #miles per gallon expected to be used driving home
      nighttime=False
      headlights_out=True

      can_drive=battery_charged==True and got_car==True and drunk==False and gas*mpg>=distance==True and headlights_out==False or nighttime==False
      print(can_drive)

      if can_drive==True:
          print("Drive home.")
      else:
          print("Do not drive home.")
```

It should print False since there is not enough gas to make it the full distance home but it prints true.

Comment: Please provide value of battery_charged to be able to answer your question. Also, suggest you to properly group the logics under parenthesis. Eg. (True and False) or True or (False and True) and True has different meaning than: True and False or True or False and True and True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`can_drive` is a bit verbose, and you should use parentheses in your condition since `and` has a higher precedence than `or`, so you can use the following:

```py
can_drive= battery_charged and got_car and not drunk and gas * mpg >= distance and (not headlights_out or not nighttime)
```

You can also improve the code that follows the declaration of `can_drive`:

```py
if can_drive:
    print("Drive home.")
else:
    print("Do not drive home.")
```

Keep in mind that comparing a bolean to `True` is redundant, so just use the boolean when you want to check that it is `True` or use `not` if you want to check if this is `False`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate your answer very much.

Answer (score 0):

You want to force the condition to evaluate the `or` only the data that you want it to by using parentheses `()`.

For example, you want `can_drive` to be true only if `headlights_out` is false or `nighttime` is true:

```
can_drive = battery_charged==True and got_car==True and drunk==False and gas*mpg>=distance==True and (headlights_out==False or nighttime==False)
```